# URLRewriting a single php file in several .html pages using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, seo

I have a php page   group.php?id=58 with a parameter in the url which indicate to the page which text and which images to display. Also it say which META TAGS to create.

So group.php?id=58 and group.php?id=85 will produce 2 differents pages.

I would like to know how to URLRewrite these pages.
For example group.php?id=58 display content about pharmacy, I would like to rename it pharmacy.html
group.php?id=85 display content about restaurant, I would like to rename it restaurant.

I guess I have to write something in .htaccess? But what?

Comment: I suggest you ask google about examples or a tutorial about request rewriting using .htaccess style files. There are millions of millions of such examples in the internet.

Comment: ok. I tried many things like:

RewriteRule   group.php?id=58  iphone.html
RewriteRule   subfolder/group.php?id=58  subfolder/iphone.html
RewriteRule   http://mywebsite/subfolder/group.php?id=58  http://mywebsite/subfolder/iphone.html

but nothing work.

Someone can help please?

Comment: Is the use of .htaccess style files enabled at all in your http server? And where did you place that file? And did you remember to place a `RewriteEngine on` before those rules?

Comment: Yes -> RewriteEngine on  .htaccess is on the root folder     .htaccess is enable

Comment: Please post your current .htaccess file, where it is located, and what happens for some urls you request. Include any entries in the http servers error log. Don't do that in a comment, please use the `edit` button above right below your question.